# Sitting in first class with a standard class ticket

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, civil-law, consumer-protection, travel

Sitting in first class with a standard class ticket

Meet Bob. Bob purchased a ticket from Bristol to Exeter on a standard class seat. However, upon boarding the train he conveniently finds that the whole first class cabin is empty and helps himself to one of the plusher seats. What legal offence (s) has Bob committed, and why should he be forced to go back to the standard cabins?

Is there any criminal offence?

If the criminal offence is reliant on a civil wrong like breach of contract or such, must that in itself come with proof of actual damage or loss resulting from the breach?

And if it is rooted in a civil contract term, then could those terms not be seen to be unfair and unenforceable as unduly benefiting the merchant with no discernible benefit at all to the consumer?

Another line of thinking is that if Bob possesses some protected characteristic, the most obvious one being disability, less straightforward possibilities perhaps including race or others that are "disproportionately correlated" with having less money then perhaps the facts can be crammed into a frame in which the operator must prove that enforcing the wastage of these seats is a proportional means of achieving a reasonable aim (which cannot simply be limited to profit making).

Comment: "Is there any criminal offence?": Theft of services?  He's using a service for which he hasn't paid.

Comment: Is your final paragraph really saying, *inter alia*, that having an empty first class carriage is racist because black people are poor?

Comment: But it's basically like food that Tesco couldn't sell by its sell by date, and then puts out by the skip. Is that theft? The thing being stolen is being wasted and discarded anyway. It has no value.

Comment: @Rick something like that... I had a long day.

Comment: @Rick well actually - not entirely. I think it is more suggesting a possibility rather that the law views it as such.

Comment: @phoog in any case if you can cite a source that it is a crime then put it in an answer that explains how.

Comment: "as unduly benefiting the merchant with no discernible benefit at all to the consumer?" - what does this mean? If Bob didn't discern a benefit why did he sit in the "plusher seat" in First Class?

Comment: @phoog "Theft of services" isn't generally a crime English law - but as kaya3 found there is a much more specific law.

Comment: “Stealing” discarded items is a pretty hot topic in a few other questions here…. Anyway, what @Lag said, if you want a more plush seat you gotta pay for it.  What’s hard to understand about that?

Comment: @Lag of course there is a benefit to Bob  in sitting in a plusher seat. But there is no benefit to the consumer in a contract term that forbids them from sitting in an otherwise entirely empty carriage just because he hadn't paid an additional premium. Let's suppose then the possibility was that a first class ticket would guarantee you a first class seat but a general/standard ticket would grant you a first come first served seat as available where you were forced to yield a seat to paying first class passengers. The term of the contract that overrides this situation doesn't benefit consumers

Comment: At all and in fact to any arguable extent to which it could be said to benefit the merchant it could only do so by harming the consumer's interests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob has breached regulation 4 of [The Railways (Penalty Fares) Regulations 2018](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2018/366/contents/made) and may be liable, under regulations 5 and 9, to pay a penalty fare:

> 4(1) A person travelling by, present on, or leaving a train must, if required to do so by or on behalf of an operator, produce **a valid travel ticket.**
>
> [...]
>
> 5(1) Subject to regulations 6, 7 and 10, if a person fails to produce a platform ticket or **a valid travel ticket in accordance with regulation 4, a collector may charge that person a penalty fare.**
>
> [...]
>
> 9(1) Where a penalty fare is charged under regulation 5(1) to a person travelling by, present on, or leaving a train, the amount of that penalty fare is **£20 or twice the full single fare applicable, whichever is greater.**

However:

One of the train operating companies on Bob's route, GWR, may - or may not - apply their [Revenue Protection Policy](https://www.gwr.com/help-and-support/penalties-and-enforcements) instead:

> We have staff specially trained to deal with fare evasion and revenue protection and fraud. Some of them can conduct interviews under caution and report people to our Prosecutions department.
>
> If you did not buy a ticket when you had the chance, what happens next will depend on which member of staff asks to see your ticket.
>
> **If you are stopped by an inspector, they may**:
>
> - Charge you a full price Anytime ticket for your journey (with no discount).
> - Report you to our Prosecutions department – which could mean you have to go to court.
>
> **If you are stopped by a train manager or conductor, they may**:
>
> - Charge you a full price Anytime ticket for your journey (with no discount).
> - Give you an Unpaid Fare Notice.
>
> We also have Ticket Examiners who can issue Unpaid Fare / Penalty Fare Notices, as well as charge full price Anytime ticket for your journey (with no discount).

Note: This policy does not specifically mention being found in First Class with a Standard Class ticket, and the use of *may* throughout, suggests that the inspector etc may have some discretion as to whether to apply the policy or to issue a penalty fare under the Regulations - presumably depending on the particular circumstances.

Comment: The policy actually *does* specifically define "valid travel ticket" in such a way that a standard class ticket is not valid for travelling in first class - see 3(2)(a)(vi) [here](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2018/366/regulation/3/made).

Comment: That's a link to the Regs, not the TOC policy

Comment: Okay, then only the question as to the constitutionality of the regulations and whether or not it constitutes indirect discrimination under the equality act remains.

Answer (score 4):

This would be an offence under section 5(3)(a) of the [Regulation of Railways Act 1889](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/52-53/57/section/5):

> (3) If any person—
>
> - (a) Travels or attempts to travel on a railway without having previously paid his fare, and with intent to avoid payment thereof;
> - ...
>
> he shall be liable on summary conviction to a fine ...

The Crown Prosecution Service has [a summary of transport offences](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/transport-offences), which says of the above offence:

> *"Intent to avoid payment"* does not require a dishonest intent, just an intent to avoid payment of the sum actually due: *Browning v Floyd* [1946] 2 All E.R. 367: where a man used the return portion of a non-transferable ticket given to him by his wife who had not used it, he was guilty of the offence and she was guilty of aiding and abetting him.

In the case of travelling in first class on a standard ticket, you would be avoiding payment of the "sum actually due", since a first class ticket is more expensive.

Comment: I'm still not completely sure that the differential is "actually due": if it is due merely by virtue of unfair and accordingly unenforceable terms of the civil contract of carriage, then perhaps it is not truly ultimately actually due.

Comment: @JosephP. The "sum actually due" here means the fare for a ticket valid for the journey; it is the fact that the passenger did not pay that fare, and intended not to pay that fare, which makes them guilty of the offence. Note that the phrase "sum actually due" does not appear in the text of section 5(3)(a), only the word "fare", so the defence you propose would depend on a claim that the price of a first class ticket is not the "fare" for a journey in first class. That seems absurd to me, but if you want advice about mounting a legal defence along these lines you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139730/discussion-on-answer-by-kaya3-sitting-in-first-class-with-a-standard-class-ticke).